# Image Get Requests with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, angularjs

I am storing the the source string of an image to be rendered in HTML in the AngularJS controller, however it yields a 404 before the Angular controller is initialized.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="Cont">
      <img src="{{imageSource}}">
 </div>
```

Angular controller:

```
 var Cont = function($scope) {
      $scope.imageSource = '/tests.png';
 }
```

And the error I get (`%7D%7D` corresponds to the `{{` in the template).

```
 GET https://localhost:9000/%7B%7BimageSource%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I prevent this from happening? That is, only load the image when the Angular controller has been initialized?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Try replacing your src with ng-src for more info see [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc):

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

```
 <div ng-controller="Cont">
      <img ng-src="{{imageSource}}">
 </div>
```

Comment: It is better to use data-ng-controller and data-ng-src so that the HTML is valid.

Answer (score 6):

If someone is searching the solution for styling background-image then use this:

```
<div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{ image.source }})'}">...</div>
```

Comment: It is bad practice to use Interpolation with ngStyle.
Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle