# Angular.js - Filter in img src tag

Tags: ajax, solr, angularjs

We use Angular mainly for our search form, which is pretty complex. We use **Solr** as search framework and get our search results via **AJAX/JSONP**, which works perfectly.

There should be an image in every search result, but it can happen that there is none. 
I use a filter to prevent nasty "X"s in the Internet Explorer when there is no img-URL in my search result.

```
angular.module('solr.filter', []).
    filter('searchResultImg', function() {      
        return function(input) {
            if (typeof(input) == "undefined") {
                return "http://test.com/logo.png";
            } else { 
                return input;
            }
        };
});
```

My linked image looks like this in the source code:

```
<a href="{{doc.url}}"><img src="{{doc.image_url | searchResultImg}}"/></a>
```

Like I said, the infos are delivered correctly, the "problem" I have is that Firebug sends a GET request with the Angular src like:

```
http://test.com/foldername/%7B%7Bdoc.image_url%20|%20searchResultImg%7D%7D
```

The link is edited, so it won't work. Else customer freak out ;)

Does anyone have experience with this behaviour or knows a better way to set filters for src-tags?

Comment: your first problem you can solve thru onerror attr <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124866/onerror-attribute-of-img-is-executing-javascript-to-change-image-but-it-did-n"> How to use </a>

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try replacing `src` with `ng-src` for more info see [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12922538/1207991).

```
<a href="{{doc.url}}"><img ng-src="{{doc.image_url | searchResultImg}}"/></a>
```

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.