# AngularJS error when displaying images?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am filling in `<img src=` tags using AngularJS, so urls in my html are:

```
<img src='[[profile.image]]'>
```

When I load the page the image shows but the get errors in the Javascript console too:

```
GET [[profile.image]] 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

So the browser is trying to fetch the image before Angular has interpolated the value right? Then when Angular sets the value the browser fetches again and this time shows the image.

How can I either get Angular to do this earlier, or get the browser to wait? I don't like having the error exposed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image Get Requests with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922509/image-get-requests-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Angular has a special directive just for this case: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc

```html
<img ng-src="{{profile.img}}" />
```

Comment: angularjs is awesome. :)