# Expression evaluation in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in somearray">
    <img src="{{ item.url }}" />
</li>
```

For every item the browser makes a GET request that is an encoded expression, for example:
  "http://someurl.com/somepath/blalba/1/%7B%7Bitem.url%7D%7D". Although it does load these images properly, it makes unnecessary requests. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image Get Requests with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922509/image-get-requests-with-angularjs)

Comment: Yes, it is. I did some searching but apparently my keywords were wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in somearray">
    <img ng-src="{{item.url}}" />
</li>
```