# ng-repeat: How to initialize default item as selected

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to initialize a list of item using ng-repeat.

```
<div class="item" ng-click="selectedProject(fpItem)" data-id="{{fpProjectItem.id}}" ng-repeat="fpItem in fpItems">
   <img src="{{fpItem.thumbnail}}" />
    <span class="item-title">{{fpItemDetails.projectname}}</span>
</div>
```

It gives an error

```
.../location/fpItem.thumbnail%7D%7D net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

How to resolve this.

Also I want to initialize default selected value. How can i do.

Comment: you're asking two questions here: first your file is not found so the file `$scope.fpItems` is trying to load is not the correct path. second, set one of the values to the `ng-model`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922509/image-get-requests-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-src for your image. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

For determining the first item in the ng-repeat use `$first`, or  `$index === 0`.

For example add the ang attribute `ng-class="{'selected':$first}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing 
    
 in your code to
    . 
 with src the path is not resolved.

Comment: Use `ng-src` instead of `src` so  that it can get the path dynamically.