# angularjs:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I use angularjs in laravel5.4 ,I get this Error in my console I dont know why it happen because the source of prb like showing in the console caused by this link of image :

```
<img class="lazy" src="/{% food.image_principale %}">
```

The think is this image is displaying correctly but in console I have this:

```
 GET http://livrer/%7B%%20item.getData().image_principale%20%%7D 400 (Bad Request)   %7B%%20item.getData().image_principale%20%%7D:1
```

I dont understand why the console show an error where it is not because I get what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question has been asked (and answered) before already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922509/image-get-requests-with-angularjs).

Short answer: Replace `src` inside the html-attribute with `ng-src`.

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem. [(Source)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)